# Ajax post is working as put (is processing, but as put) , how to correct

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Ajax post is working as put (which for editing data), I'm doing with adding new data though, how to correct?

I already read through all the template, and I does follow the template to get here, but still need a hand.

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/product/',
  type : 'POST',    // post for adding data
  dataType : 'json',
  contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
  data :JSON.stringify(send_Edit_API_Data) , 
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken       // for authorized/safty reason
  },
  success : function(result) {
    console.log("SUCCESS", result)
  },
  error:  function(response){
    console.log("ERROR",response);
  }
});
```

I even add this (this header is used to indicate that the request should be treated as a POST request even if it is being sent as a PUT request) but still working as put:

```
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'POST');
      },
```

---

- the full version of code if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
   
</head>
<body>
  


  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/product",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
            return response.ipcs
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" id="Delete_Data" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },

          
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "name", title: "name" },
          { data: "group", title: "group" }
        ]
      });


      table.draw()
  

      var rowData; 

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;
  
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });


      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data") {
          inputFields.val("");
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });


      function editRow_website(id){
        

            
        var device_id=document.getElementById("device_id"+id);  
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);  
        var group=document.getElementById("group"+id);

        
        let getEditData = {
          "device_id": device_id,
          "email_data": name,
          "address_data": group,
        }

        document.getElementById("#editid input").value = device_id
       

        
      }
      

      $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {  
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        
        console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)

        confirmDelete(id) 
      });

      function deleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/product?device_id="+ id,
          type:'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }


      function confirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("sure to delete？")== true) {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable();
          var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
          deleteData(id);

          if (row.length > 0) {
            row.remove().draw();
            console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
          }
        } else{
          none
        }

      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class ="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new" onclick="AddRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New</button> -->
        <button type="button" id="AddedNew_Data" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" " onclick="AddRow()">Add New02</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">device_id:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_device_id" class="col-form-label">Device ID:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_device_id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_name" class="col-form-label">name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_name">
            </div>
            
            <!-- Additional form fields -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field1" class="col-form-label">group:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_data_group">
            </div>
            
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Send message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script>
    function AddRow() {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")
      save();


     
      console.log("Saved Data_added_API_Data:", send_Edit_API_Data);
      $("#input_edit_device_id").val("");
      $("#input_edit_name").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_group").val("");

    }



      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/product',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      data: JSON.stringify(send_Edit_API_Data),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
      },
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'POST');
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log("SUCCESS", result);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR", response);
      }
    });



    function editRow(data) {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      console.log("EDIT=====", data);
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/product/",   /// api change ///
        type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
        },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("SUCCESS",response);
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      })
      }
    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }

    
    </script>

  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem") || [];
    
    function save() {
      var itemValue_device_id = document.getElementById("input_edit_device_id").value || "";
      var itemValue_edit_name = document.getElementById("input_edit_name").value || "";
      var itemValue_data_group = document.getElementById("input_edit_data_group").value || "";

      console.log("itemValue_device_id", itemValue_device_id, typeof(itemValue_device_id));
      console.log("itemValue_edit_name", itemValue_edit_name, typeof(itemValue_edit_name));
      console.log("itemValue_data_group", itemValue_data_group, typeof(itemValue_data_group));


      let send_Edit_API_Data = {
        device_id:itemValue_device_id,
        name:itemValue_edit_name,
        group: itemValue_data_group,


      }
      console.log("send_Edit_API_Data", send_Edit_API_Data);

      editRow(send_Edit_API_Data)
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

such as I'm adding new data [adding new data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dxde.png)

1. By clicking "Add New02" button
2. I fill up the new data (device_id: 'string-new01' and etc) console all get it
3. the new data is saved as "send_Edit_API_Data"
4. use ajax send to server
5. **when I refresh, the new data is not added**

the `{detail: 'No IPC with this device_id: string-new01 found'}` I assume is edit mode, the put method, that server tells back No IPC with this device_id: string-new01 found

---

Damm, I just found out, both "add" and "edit" button run `save()` function, which  **only**  in use `editRow( )` API, therefore, add is run as edit

```
    function save() {
      // var getData = document.getElementById("#sendData form").val
      var itemValue_device_id = document.getElementById("input_edit_device_id").value || "";
      var itemValue_edit_name = document.getElementById("input_edit_name").value || "";
      var itemValue_data_group = document.getElementById("input_edit_data_group").value || "";



      console.log("itemValue_device_id", itemValue_device_id, typeof(itemValue_device_id));
      console.log("itemValue_edit_name", itemValue_edit_name, typeof(itemValue_edit_name));
      console.log("itemValue_data_group", itemValue_data_group, typeof(itemValue_data_group));


      let send_Edit_API_Data = {
        device_id:itemValue_device_id,
        name:itemValue_edit_name,
        group: itemValue_data_group,


      }
      console.log("send_Edit_API_Data", send_Edit_API_Data);

      editRow(send_Edit_API_Data)          
    }
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working as expected? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Your ajax code is simply sending a request.  How you *handle* that request is the issue.

Comment: The variable `send_Edit_API_Data` implies that you are making an edit (PUT).

Comment: "edit" is correct the existing one, I want "add" to add the new data. When user iput them,I both save in  `send_Edit_API_Data` and send to server.   However, the new data cannot create in server

Comment: I tried to make question more details @Nico Haase  pls take a look

Comment: *the full version of code* - the issue is not with the HTMl/JavaScript/jQuery, the issue is what the server is doing with the provided data.

Comment: if I use by Fast API tool, the post work as add, but we don't know the code behind it, and I want to do by my `HTMl/JavaScript/jQuery` side, should work, just the format problem

Comment: `url: "http://http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/product//",` - it looks pretty obvious to me that this won't work

Comment: sor, I just change to `"http://http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/product/"` but other part also need to correct too

Comment: Damm, I just found out, both "add" and "edit" button run `save()` function, which  **only**  in use `editRow( )` api, therefore, add is run as edit